# Not all resize events get registered by jQuery $(window).resize

Tags: jquery, window-resize

What I've noticed is that, when the browser screen is manually resized, the `$(window).resize()` event gets triggered and the contained function executes perfectly fine.

However, when a browser screen is snapped to a side of the screen (f.e. using <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd>, <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>Down</kbd>,...), the resize event doesn't get fired, so the contained function doesn't execute and my webpage doesn't "recognise" the resizing.

Is it me, or am I missing something here?

I'd be glad if someone could explain to me why it behaves like this.

Comment: Which browser is that? Working fine here in Chrome 33. Mini-fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LNa6m/1/

Comment: Well this is strange, I can't seem to reproduce it anymore. I was using Chrome as you are, but it looks like my question isn't true, indeed. Well, question solved, then!